# What is the best practice to host multiple website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently I have hosted 150+ sites in one AWS EC2 instance. And continuously I am adding more websites, approximate 10 to 15 websites per month. So I need suggestion for this. One EC2 instance is good or I need to divide it in multiple EC2 instances. And another thing EC2 auto scaling is good for this or not ?. I can't use beanstalk due to the limitation.

Comment: Auto scaling is good for balancing load on server. Think about ECS container also.

Comment: @aviboy2006 ok I will check

Comment: @aviboy2006 I am new to this. Can you give me some reference link or tutorial for setup multiple websites in ECS container.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by 'good'.

Good for your wallet is to host them all on a single ec2 instance, in a single region and hope that singe instance (or AZ) doesn't go down or have problems.

Good for uptime would be to host all of the websites together on multiple ec2 instances, across multiple AZ's and use a load balancer to distribute traffic across several identical instances.

Better for uptime and performance  would be multiple larger ec2 instances in multiple AZ's behind a load balancer

Best for uptime, performance and your wallet would mean multiple smaller ec2 instances, behind a load balancer and with autoscaling enabled to bring up (and turn off) instances depending on traffic load.

Besides the above, you can also offload some of your static assets (css, js, images etc) to an s3 bucket which should save some $$ and reduce the load on your web servers (thus needing smaller or less of them) and then put cloudfront in front of everything to cache assets/pages closer to your end users.

So lots of options, but what you are doing now is perhaps a bit risky.

Comment: Good means easy to manage and best practices for manage multiple website hosting.And I am already using s3 & cloudfront but mainly I need a suggestion for manage hosting of multiple website.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking on a perspective of cost saving I would suggest to go with docker and ECS. Since you are adding multiple websites there's a chance some of the websites will have more or less load. Use ECS tasks along with application load balancer and autoscaling group. You'll have reliability and separation between applications.